# How can I specify server-side encryption of Amazon S3 objects with PowerShell?

Tags: encryption, powershell, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, server-side

Would someone explain how to enable Amazon S3 server-side encryption in a PowerShell script? I'm using the sample code below but when I check encryption in the AWS Console or Cloudberry S3 Explorer Pro the encryption type is still set to 'none'. Using AWS / Cloudberry to do this manually after files are uploaded isn't feasible because the script is to be deployed to 200+ servers, each with it's own bucket in S3. Here's a snippet of code from the script:

```
$TestFile="testfile.7z"
$S3ObjectKey = "mytestfile.7z"
#Create Amazon PutObjectRequest.
$AmazonS3 = [Amazon.AWSClientFactory]::CreateAmazonS3Client($S3AccessKeyID,$S3SecretKeyID)
$S3PutRequest = New-Object Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest 
$S3PutRequest.BucketName = $S3BucketName
$S3PutRequest.Key = $S3ObjectKey
$S3PutRequest.FilePath = $TestFile
$S3Response = $AmazonS3.PutObject($S3PutRequest)
```

I've tried inserting the following without success (before the $S3Response line):

```
$S3PutRequest.ServerSideEncryption
```

When the above is added I get this message in the output but the file is still not tagged as encrypted on S3:

```
MemberType          : Method
OverloadDefinitions : {Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest WithServerSideEncryptionMethod(Amazon.S3.Model.ServerSideEncryptionMethod encryption)}
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Management.Automation.PSMethod
Value               : Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest WithServerSideEncryptionMethod(Amazon.S3.Model.ServerSideEncryptionMethod encryption)
Name                : WithServerSideEncryptionMethod
IsInstance          : True
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add:

```
$S3PutRequest.WithServerSideEncryptionMethod([Amazon.S3.Model.ServerSideEncryptionMethod]::AES256)
```

Or:

```
$S3PutRequest.ServerSideEncryptionMethod = [Amazon.S3.Model.ServerSideEncryptionMethod]::AES256
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CloudBerry, it has its own PowerShell snapin

```
Add-PSSnapin CloudBerryLab.Explorer.PSSnapin

$s3 = Get-CloudS3Connection -Key XXXXXXX -Secret YYYYYYY
$destFolder = $s3 | Select-CloudFolder -path "mybucket"
$local = Get-CloudFilesystemConnection
$srcFolder = $local | Select-CloudFolder -path "c:\myzips"
$srcFolder | Copy-CloudItem $destFolder -filter "testfile.7z" -SSE
```

Notice *-SSE* parameter in the *Copy-CloudItem* command.
Some helpful examples can be found on their blog: http://blog.cloudberrylab.com/search?q=powershell

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't want to install the Cloudberry app on all the servers this will be running on though. I have scripted the AWS for .Net installer and am using that instead, since it's free.